# How to handle exceptions in a nested method chain and revert changes in intermediate method?

Tags: python

```
def method1(self):
    try:
        self.method2()
    except CustomException:
        print("Error")
def method2(self):
    self.a = 3
    self.method3()

def method3(self):
    raise CustomException
```

How can I cancel the assignment `self.a = 3` in the intermediate method (`method2`), when the exception in `method3` occurs?

Comment: it depends. The most transparent way is to do it _in `method2`_ (either deleting the attribute or assigning e.g. `None` to it) then rethrow the error.

Comment: Should I add exception handling also in method2, and in the "except" clause raise the exception again, so that it is caught by method1?

Comment: That's what I suggested, yes.

Comment: The way you do this (as a kind of rollback) depends on whether self.a existed and what its value was before you caught the exception. Surely it would be better to call method3() and assign self.a afterwards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Handle the exception in method 2 to reset the variable and rethrow the error, so you can catch it in method 1:

```py
def method1(self):
    try:
        self.method2()
    except CustomException:
        print("Error")

def method2(self):
    self.a = 3
    try:
        self.method3()
    except CustomException as e:  # Save exception in e
        self.a = None             # Reset self.a; You could also delete it
        raise e                   # Rethrow error

def method3(self):
    raise CustomException
```

Comment: That's _not_ rethrowing the error, it's creating a new one.

Comment: What if self.a previously had a value other than 3? You would set it to None. So that's only a valid reset if its original value was None

Comment: Indeed, as @DarkKnight said in a comment, it would be better to assign self.a AFTER trying self.method3; as for REthrowing the exception, have a look at this: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a proper rollback you have to consider whether (or not) self.a previously existed. And, if it did, what its value was.

The technique shown here will perform a genuine rollback by either removing self.a (if it didn't previously exist) or setting it to its original value (if it did exist). The caveat however is that you have to choose an unambiguous placeholder which you can reasonably test with an assertion

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    ...

class MyClass:
    PLACEHOLDER = '_placeholder_'
    def __init__(self, create: bool):
        if create:
            self.a = 999

    def method1(self):
        try:
            self.method2()
        except CustomException:
            print("Error")

    def method2(self):
        try:
            assert not hasattr(self, MyClass.PLACEHOLDER)
            setattr(self, MyClass.PLACEHOLDER, self.a)
        except AttributeError:
            # we get here if self.a didn't previously exist
            # this also means that the placeholder attribute will not exist
            pass

        self.a = 3

        try:
            self.method3()
        except CustomException as e:
            try:
                # reassign from placeholder
                self.a = getattr(self, MyClass.PLACEHOLDER)
                # delete the placeholder attribute
                delattr(self, MyClass.PLACEHOLDER)
            except AttributeError:
                # we get here if the placeholder did not exist - i.e., self.a didn't exist
                delattr(self, 'a')
            raise e

    def method3(self):
        raise CustomException

mc = MyClass(True)
mc.method1()
print(mc.a)

mc = MyClass(False)
mc.method1()
print(mc.a)
```

**Output:**

```
Error
999
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/****/Python/Sep21.py", line 83, in <module>
    print(mc.a)
          ^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'a'
```